# How to display a complete html page when I have it's source html in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to display another html page on my html page, that html page is generated. So I don't have it's src, only the content. It has doctype, head, body, all stuff. So I decided to use iframe. The problem is that I can't assign the whole text to a variable, as I get errors, that there is an unsupported character, like "<" etc. How to deal with it?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
var iframeDocument = document.getElementById("myIframe").contentDocument;
var ss = "
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>";
iframeDocument.write(ss);
iframeDocument.close();
}
```

So my problem is how to escape that text so it won't cause browser errors?
Also html content is generated dynamically, so in my code there is no that text, there is struts action variable. But after my code gots executed in browser, that's what I see in there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: Don't you mean `ss = "...`? Also, you should escape the `"` signs in the string.

Comment: I suppose I have to do that on my server side.

Comment: Or you could use single quotes on the outside: `var ss = '<div class="some-class">Enter HTML please</div>';`

Answer (score 1):

The **easiest** way to solve this is to create a new aspx page, that creates that html you need in your `iframe` and set the src of the `iframe` to that aspx page (or php, depends on what you are using).

So lets say you create a new aspx page called `Frame.aspx`. You then add `<iframe src="Frame.aspx?SomeParameter=SomeValue" />` to your parent window.

This is a much nicer approach and much more maintainable. Also it prevents having the iFrame contents twice (once in your javascript variable and once as content of the iframe).